# Call a procedure using another procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I am trying to call two procedures using another procedure in Oracle.
This is the query that I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_reproc_tickets(p_Dta_Processo IN OUT DATE,
                           p_Cod_Loja_Ini     IN OUT NUMBER,
                           p_Status   OUT VARCHAR2,
                           p_Retorno  OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    l_Cod_loja number;
    l_p_Data date;
    l_p_Mes number;     
          
    BEGIN

    l_Cod_loja := p_Cod_Loja_Ini;
    l_p_Data := p_Dta_Processo;
    l_p_Mes := To_Number('1' || To_Char(Trunc(p_Dta_Processo), 'RRMM'));

    p_Qtd_ticket_dia(l_Cod_loja, l_p_Data, l_p_Data);  
               
    P_Qtd_ticket_mes(l_Cod_loja, l_p_Mes); 

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_Status  := '0';
        p_Retorno := SQLERRM;
    END;
```

I just want the procedure p_reproc_tickets to be able to execute the procedures p_Qtd_ticket_dia and p_Qtd_ticket_mes. That's the full error:

```
Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'P_QTD_TICKET_DIA' must be declared
Line: 17
Text: p_Qtd_ticket_dia(l_Cod_loja, l_p_Data, l_p_Data);

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 17
Text: p_Qtd_ticket_dia(l_Cod_loja, l_p_Data, l_p_Data);

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'P_QTD_TICKET_MES' must be declared
Line: 19
Text: p_Qtd_ticket_mes(l_Cod_loja, l_p_mes);

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 19
Text: p_Qtd_ticket_mes(l_Cod_loja, l_p_mes);
```

Comment: And are you sure that these procedures exist? and as you have 'Q' in uppercase in the names, are you sure that you did not do something like create .. procedure "p_Qtd_ticket_dial"...? If you did so, remove these procedures and recreate them without using '"' around the names.

Comment: either you created the procs with double quotes so as to be case sensitive, or they dont actually exist, or they exist in another schema, or you have synonyms pointing to these procs owned by another schema but you don't have exec privs on them. Check all of these out.

Comment: I added the full error to the the question and I'm sure that the procedures I'm trying to call exists and it was not created with quotes marks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you that tryed to help me.

The procedures p_Qtd_ticket_dia and p_Qtd_ticket_mes only existed inside a package. So I just added the package name like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_reproc_tickets(p_Dta_Processo IN OUT DATE,
                           p_Cod_Loja_Ini     IN OUT NUMBER,
                           p_Status   OUT VARCHAR2,
                           p_Retorno  OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    l_Cod_loja number;
    l_p_Data date;
    l_p_Mes number;     
          
    BEGIN

    l_Cod_loja := p_Cod_Loja_Ini;
    l_p_Data := p_Dta_Processo;
    l_p_Mes := To_Number('1' || To_Char(Trunc(p_Dta_Processo), 'RRMM'));

    etl.pk_vendas.p_Qtd_ticket_dia(l_Cod_loja, l_p_Data, l_p_Data);  
               
    etl.pk_vendas.P_Qtd_ticket_mes(l_Cod_loja, l_p_Mes); 

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_Status  := '0';
        p_Retorno := SQLERRM;
    END;
```